# Convert from Salesforce.com sObject[] to .NET DataSet

Tags: c#, dataset, salesforce

I am taking over an application that currently has data in a database, but we are converting to Salesforce, the previous developers passed Datasets to the controls to be bound and displayed. In order to try and make my life easier, I would love to be able to have a wrapper that would take the sObject[] from Salesforce and convert it to a DataSet that I can pass back. I have been racking my brain and can't seem to see a way to do this. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up figuring it out. I had to use Reflection to parse the private Fields that were returned as a part of the object, but have been able to do it.

Comment: Reflection is the way to go on this, especially since SF objects can have custom fields and relationships. I've done a similar thing myself a while back. +1.